# How to add a Python application to OS X right-click menu?

Tags: macos, applications, python

I have made a Python-based application that plays a slideshow. I want to add shortcut on the right-click menu of a folder and play the slideshow.

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use a service created by Automator to call your python script.

[image: Automator Service example]

Once your service is created, it will be available in the service submenu of your contextual menu.

Comment: couldn't get it to work, from the contextual menu I have new folder action, and I don't understand how will this launch python app..

Comment: @san New Folder Action is unrelated. Put your Python app in the Run Shell Script box with the shell set to Python. Make sure the inputs are set correctly, then make sure that the service is set to receive folders in Finder. Save the Automator as a service and it will show in the services menu.

Comment: I do not want in service menu, i want to add to right click of any folder in the finder window.

Comment: @san Yes, it will be in the right-click menu, under the services menu.

Comment: i have an executable script at below location that can be used start slide show 

`~/Development/python/slideShow/scripts/slideshow`

Comment: I also tried this `import os`
`os.system(os.path.join(os.getcwd(),'Development/python/slideShow/scripts/slideshow'))` but this too didn't worked.

I had python selected in shell and although workflow completed without error.

Comment: @san Since you haven't provided the actual script, I can only guess, but I presume you provide your script with the path as an argument, therefore you need to pass the path as an argument through Automator, then add it to th context menu, which is exactly what my answer says. Use the example in the screenshot if you need help writing the actual script, but this probably isn't the best place to ask for the actual programming — my answer presumes a fully-working script.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/12146/discussion-between-san-and-grgarside)